# Setting wrapper div to position absolute shrinks wrapper to arbitrary width

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I'm running into an issue with `position: absolute` and I can't find an answer anywhere that explains why it's happening.

I have a flexbox container inside a wrapper with two children that are each set to `flex-basis: 50%`. When I set `position: absolute` on the wrapper div, the wrapper shrinks in an unpredictable way.

See the code below:

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer-wrapper .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}
.outer-wrapper .wrapper .flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.outer-wrapper .wrapper .flex-container .flex-item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="flex-container">

      <div class="flex-item">
         Some Text That Is Long
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item">
         Some Text
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">

      <div class="flex-item">
         Some Text
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item">
         Some Text
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Removing line 6 in the CSS causes the flex-container to expand to the full width of the parent and each flex child takes up 50% of the width, as expected. However, when I set the wrapper div to `position: absolute`, the wrapper div shrinks to what seems like an arbitrary width and the text in the flex-children breaks onto multiple lines.

My questions:

- Why does setting `position: absolute` on the wrapper div cause the wrapper div to shrink smaller than its content?
- How does the browser determine what width to shrink the wrapper div to? It seems to me like it would either shrink to be as small as possible without introducing line breaks into the text, or would shrink as small as possible while still fitting the longest word, but instead it's shrinking to somewhere in the middle (it only introduces one line break in a string of short words).
- Is there a way, while still using flexbox and `position: absolute` in this way, to force the browser to not shrink the wrapper smaller than its content (unless there is a max-width set on the wrapper)?

Really appreciate any help! This has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does setting position: absolute on the wrapper div cause the wrapper div to shrink smaller than its content?
>
> How does the browser determine what width to shrink the wrapper div to?

The trick is the use of `flex-basis::50%`. You are in a situation where you are using a shrink-to-fit container (`position:absolute` element) and at the same time you are using percentage value inside the `flex-basis`. So the browser is first calculating the width of the container (ignoring the `flex-basis`) then the width calculated will be used as reference for the `flex-basis`.

Here is an illustration of what is happening:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
}

 .wrapper .flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

 .wrapper .flex-container .flex-item {
  /*flex-basis: 50%;*/
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text That Is Long
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="top:100px;">
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text That Is Long
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how in the first example (without flex-basis) the width is equal to the largest content. In the second example you will see that the total width didn't change but we made the flex items equal in width.

The same logic also happen with `inline-block` or `float` or any shrink-to-fit container.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid red;
}

 .wrapper .flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

 .wrapper .flex-container .flex-item {
  /*flex-basis: 50%;*/
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text That Is Long
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text That Is Long
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 50%;">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

To get what you want it's clear that you need to not use `flex-basis:50%` and consider a different idea to get the same width.

Here is one using CSS grid as I think it would be tedious with flexbox:

```css
.wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
}

 .wrapper .flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
}

 .wrapper .flex-container .flex-item {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text That Is Long
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      Some Text
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is shrinking is since you are setting position absolute without specifying a width.

Block element feature of having the full width of the parent's content area will not be honored when an element is absolute positioned.

If you want to retain the width (100% of the container) of a block element, then set the width of the absolute element `.wrapper` to 100% and problem solved.

```
.outer-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
   position: absolute; 
   width:100%;
}

.flex-container {
   display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
   flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! That all makes sense. But what do I do if I don't want to retain the width of a block element (I don't want the wrapper to be the full width of its parent), but want the wrapper to grow just large enough to fit its content without forcing line breaks in the text? Also, can you help me understand how the browser determines the width of the wrapper if a width is not explicitly set (part 2 of my question)? I appreciate your help!

Comment: If so than remove the `flex-basis` or let me know what your trying to accomplish so I can help you achieve it. What are you trying to do by setting it to 50% when there is nothing to tell the browser how to slice it.